# Controlar valor de una variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Tengo el siguente codigo, donde hay 2 funciones de draggable/droppable.

Por cada elemento que se coloca bien, yo aumento mi variable en 1 para saber que todos los elementos se colocaron bien.

Hice otra funcion donde yo controlo esa variable que sumo, para decir que si esta variable vale 2, hago otra cosa...

Pero no me anda bien esto (el IF del 2do script no se ejecuta), necesito su ayuda.

**Este script controla los elementos colocados e incremeta la var 'totalSombras':**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var totalSombras = 0;

        $('#silueta1').droppable({
            tolerance: 'fit',
            hoverClass: 'active',
            accept: "#objeto1",
            drop: function(e, ui) {
                $(this).html(ui.draggable.remove().html());
                $(this).droppable('destroy');
                $( this )
                //.addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .attr("src", "images/jirafa.png");
                var thissound = document.getElementById('colocarSilueta');
                thissound.volume = 0.2;
                thissound.play();
                totalSombras = totalSombras + 1;
                contar(totalSombras);
            }
        });

        $('#silueta2').droppable({
            tolerance: 'fit',
            hoverClass: 'active',
            accept: "#objeto2",
            drop: function(e, ui) {
                $(this).html(ui.draggable.remove().html());
                $(this).droppable('destroy');
                $( this )
                .attr("src", "images/vaca.png");
                var thissound = document.getElementById('colocarSilueta');
                thissound.volume = 0.2;
                thissound.play();
                totalSombras = totalSombras + 1;
                contar(totalSombras);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Este script controla si la var 'totalSombras' vale 2:**

```
<script>
    jQuery(function contar(cont) {
        if (cont == 2) {
            alert("asd");
        }
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes declarar la variable fuera de la función, ejemplo:

```
<script>
    var totalSombras = 0;
    $(function () {
        $('#silueta1').droppable({
    ...
```

Y la función contar, no debes crearla con jquery, solo la función como tal:

```
<script>
    function contar(cont) {
        if (cont == 2) {
            alert("asd");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Genial, gracias mejiajuanbta